# React Native: Append Data To Prop In mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have prop called "data" that it populated with records of data initially to the state on application load. What I trying to do is append to the "data" prop based on a function that I am firing in mapDispatchToProps.

Code is currently as follows:

```
class ListScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    data: PropType.isRequired,
    nextBatchOfData: PropTypes.func,
  };

  getData = () => {
    this.props.nextBatchOfData({ some, search, params });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }) => `${id}`}
            numColumns={2}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: [...dataSelectors.getOfferResults(state)], // Attempting to append to existing state..
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  nextBatchOfData: searchParams => dispatch(actions.dataSearch.request(searchParams)),
});
```

When run the `getData()` function, the `nextBatchOfData()` prop will fire. However, the previous state gets overwritten. Is there any way to get around this?

Here is a section of my reducer where I am getting back the data:

```
[combineActions(actions.dataSearch.success, actions.dataSearch.fail)]: (
      state,
      { payload, meta, error }
    ) => {
      const hasResults = payload && !error;
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: error && payload.message,
        results: hasResults ? payload : state.results,
      };
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Why aren't you doing the append in the reducer ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout I am new to Redux. I have updated my question with a section of my reducer action for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do this is on the reducer.

You will have `state` available so the append will be more natural to be done there.